# Scrapy Error: Ignoring response <404 ...> : HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, httprequest

I am new to scrapy and this is probably quite trivial. Anyway
I get the following error:

```
INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.geographie.uni
muenchen.de/department/fiona/studium/fuer_studierende/termine/index.html/>:
HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

I have tried to change the user agent in the settings.py file without success. Does anyone have another idea?
Thank you

my code:

```
import scrapy

class DepartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'department'
    start_urls = ['http://www.geographie.uni-muenchen.de/department/fiona/studium/fuer_studierende/termine/index.html/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[2]/tbody'):
            yield {
                'Art' : row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
                'Belegfrist': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first(),
                'Klausur' : row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have slash in the end of url in `start_urls`. Without it everything should work fine.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted? You didn't do it in all questions that you asked and where someone solved your problems.